# mysql is not recognised as an inter or external command

Tags: mysql, database

I have installed xampp in `c:` drive.
I am able to run my sql from xampp,
but when I am trying to open it from cmd prompt its giving following error. Please help

> C:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysql.ece 'mysql.ece' is not recognized as an
>   internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Suggest we close this as a TYPO

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with a MySQL command being called `mysql.ece`.

Should it be `mysql.exe` instead?

Comment: ss, it was mysql.exe only

Comment: @kavitha if the answer was correct can you mark it as answered?

Answer (score 0):

change `mysql.ece`  to `mysql.exe`, you will see a file with mysql.exe in bin folder which is inside mysql folder.